# How to make swiper-slide width the same as it's child?

Tags: swiper.js

I am trying to implement a slideshow with swiperjs with `slidesPerView: 'auto'` option with the following layout:

```
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide py-3">
                    <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
                        <img src="...">
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

the problem is that no matter how small the images' width is, the slides are always 100% wide, e.g. I need to make the orange containers here as wide as their gray children:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVpBZO

I can't simply hardcode the width as I don't know it beforehand.

I tried to set `display: inline-flex` on `.swiper-slide` but it doesn't change anything.